# XCode draining memory

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, memory, viewcontroller

I'm developing an app for iPhone but it is draining memory to a point where adding text takes about 2 sec per letter. I have a total of 97 viewcontollers on my story board with 54 .h & .m viewcontroller files each. I do reuse some .h & .m files for different views in my storyboard. The problem started when I added the last 4 viewcontollers to the storyboard. With no text/buttons....in them my physical memory went from (total 4gb) 2,04gb to 9,7mb. Deleting the 4 views gave back the memory and all works fine, adding them and I have a problem. The app runs fine in the simulator and on the device with no issues. I've uninstalled XCode and reinstalled - same problem. Please advise.

Comment: OMG -- 97 vcs! xcode is gonna choke and anyways .... as jacky boy set:  'Well, that's why I don't use Storyboards'

Answer (score 0):

No need to uninstall XCode, the problem is definitly in your code somewhere! 97 Viewcontrollers? Check your code & garbage collection. Perform Xcode memory test to locate what is consuming memory!

[Tracking memory leaks](http://www.streamingcolour.com/blog/tutorials/tracking-iphone-memory-leaks/)

[Howto debug Memory leaks in Xcode tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial)

[Objective C memory management explained](http://interfacelab.com/objective-c-memory-management-for-lazy-people/)

Comment: Thanks, the views do not push or pull any data externally, it is a self contained app so I'm not sure where it could leak memory if it only displays text and a few pictures, then navigate to another view through seques. Any ideas??

Comment: Have you tried :  "build and analyze" function of Xcode.

Simply select Build -> Build and Analyze in the Xcode menu.

Comment: Tried, it said that analyze succeeded

Comment: There is no simple answer to your question since the memory leaks occurs from unreleased objects in your code. Start by debugging and searching for thoose. The link about "memory management" explains what you shall look for and how.